# Products will be shipped in the same order they . . . ordered?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

What is the correct word in the following sentence?

> Products will be shipped in the same order they [. . .] ordered.

I am guessing for *are* or *have been*, but I'm not sure. Can someone explain?

To clarify: the ordering of the products is both in the past and in the present. The shipping will take place *after* the ordering of all the products.

Comment: Both *are* and *were* work. *Have been* is rather unwieldy. And I would add an *in* at the end, though I guess it's optional for some people.

Comment: I agree but don't think the choice between *were* and *are* is completely neutral. With *are* it's more clearly stating an ongoing policy (regarding future orders). That may be a distinction that doesn't matter in context.

Comment: Also I think it'd also be neglectful not to mention that you still end up with a difficult sentence to read, given the different uses of *order*. Well, that's how it was for me, the first 8 words reminded me of when amazon ask if I want my stuff dispatched together ("in the same order") or separately. Something like "the order of shipping will be the same as that of the placement of the orders" works better for me (separates the uses of *order* more, makes the referents of "same as" more explicit, and makes it a bit more instantly obvious what kind of thing each *order* is).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with RegDwigнt that you could use either *were* or *are* here. And I strongly agree with Rupe that the repetition in the sentence of *order/ordered* in two very different senses has a disturbingly mind-numbing effect. My advice is to discard the first *order* in favor of *sequence* and to replace the second *ordered* with wording that emphasizes the arrival of the orders at the business rather than the time when the order is submitted (the two might be identical for an online business, but not necessarily identical for a business that accepts mail-in orders). Thus, for example:

> Products will be shipped in the same sequence in which orders for them reach us.

Answer (score 0):

Were. This is because in order for the product to be shipped, it has to have already have been ordered - so 'were' refers to this prior action.